# Need hibernate function that returns the index of a substring

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

I want a function in hibernate that returns the index of a specified substring, i will use that index in `substring` function, for example consider this hibernate query:

```
from PersonObject m where substring(m.description,44,4) BETWEEN :minnum and :maxnum
```

i want to use the requested function instead of the start index `44` to dynamically get the start index as this position varies for one string to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPQL function to get start position is [LOCATE](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_string_fun):

> LOCATE(string_primary, string_primary[, simple_arithmetic_expression])

Because HQL is more or less superset of JPQL, it of course works also in HQL.