# Table Field set twice in HQL only appears once in the compiled SQL

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, hql

My **HQL query** is as under (**Hibernate with MS SQL Server**)

```
SELECT...FROM...WHERE...

AND...

AND REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(**ALIAS.info**),0, CHARINDEX('@', REVERSE(**ALIAS.info**)))) in (:var1_0,:var1_1)

AND...
```

The query compiles correctly. However when I try to use the `query.list() method`, it fails. The reason for failure is the `sql query` generated is as under:

```
select...from...where...

and...

and (reverse(substring(reverse(**namedinfos2_.info**), 0, CHARINDEX('@')) in (?))

and...
```

Note that after the '`@`' it is missing the `namedinfos2_.info again`. Hence the `CHARINDEX() function` fails, as it expects `2 parameters`. 
It should have been the below:

```
and...

and (reverse(substring(reverse(**namedinfos2_.info**), 0, CHARINDEX('@', **namedinfos2_.info**)) in (?))

and---
```

> Any idea why does this happen? Or what I should be doing to fix this?

The actual query is quite long. 
An Example can be like this:

**HQL:**

```
select LastModifiedByUser.field
from namedinfo LastModifiedByUser
where REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LastModifiedByUser.info),0, CHARINDEX('@', REVERSE(LastModifiedByUser.info)))) in (:var1_0,:var1_1)
```

**Generated SQL by Hibernate**

```
select namedinfos2_.field
form namedinfo namedinfos2_
where (reverse(substring(reverse(namedinfos2_.info), 0, CHARINDEX('@')) in (?))
```

**Note-** the missing `LastModifiedByUser.info` conversion in the `CHARINDEX` method (`2nd parameter`).

Comment: I don't follow the question/issue, and you might want to clean up your code and show the full query.

Comment: The actual query is very long. I updated the query with a smaller example.

Comment: Could you tell what's the purpose of this expression?

Answer (score 0):

Could you remove the `CHARINDEX` function? I was not able to found it the [expressions functions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) section, so maybe the engine is not able to translate it correctly.

Also, you are allowed to use [native SQL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm), so you can try building simple `CHARINDEX` statement and run it in that way.

Also, you can try to use [LOCATE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16886935/1080354) as alternative of what you are doing.

Comment: I need the CHARINDEX as it was present earlier. I am converting a view to HQL, and cannot change the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a workaround by making a custom function say functionXyz() that takes input string and internally just returns something like the below.

```
return reverse(substring(reverse(namedinfos2_.info), 0, CHARINDEX('@'))
```

That is making it work, just that I everytime need to call this function. Not sure if it has an impact on performance.